# Put / Update to my MongoDb with Express, immutable error of cross _id field

Tags: mongodb, express, immutability, put

So I am sending data of a mission, the startdate and the finish date. However I am not able to put any changes into the database as it believes I get an immutable error with mongoDB... I would like to stick with using the .then method for my js code.

My other methods are working properly, I just can't get this update method right...

```
app.put('/missions/:id', function (req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    model.Mission.findById(req.params.id).then(function(Mission){
      console.log("req.body.secret_mission: ",req.body.secret_mission)
      Mission['secret_mission'] = req.body.secret_mission;
      Mission['start'] = req.body.start;
      Mission['complete'] = req.body.complete;

      Mission.update().then(function(){
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.sendStatus(201);
      });
  });
}else{
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
});
```

[Error I receive in the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdjjh.png)

Comment: Might be it think's you're inserting a new doc (and thereby generating another id prop?) There's also .findByIdAndUpdate, which might be worth a try: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Your problem is with `.update()` that should be replaced to `.save()` since update call on model instance wants fields to be defined: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update

Comment: why You want to stick with `.then` when You can use `async/await` out of box (form v.8.x.x)

Comment: @zbnrg thanks, the docs helped alot! I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use all the help provided to come up with a working solution and keep consistent to how I am calling the rest of my code. A big **thanks** to those that responded!!

Rather than setting the elements in my collection beforehand I am supposed to do it in the update request. Instead of calling 2 methods I used the findOneAndUpdate.

```
app.put('/missions/:id', function (req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    model.Mission.findOneAndUpdate(
      {'_id' : req.params.id},
      { $set: {"secret_mission" : req.body.secret_mission,
              "start" : req.body.start},
              "complete" : req.body.complete
      }).then(function(err, missions){
      if (err) return res.json({Error: err});
        res.json(missions);
    });
  } else {
    res.sendSatus(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: small fix: `.then(function(mission){` since then passes just one argument  and after enclosing `.then` use `.catch((error) => res.json({Error: error});`

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up Your code:

1. removed `req.user` check to middleware,
2. included `cors` module to not to play with CORS headers in every handler
3. used `async/await` stuff to give it more synchronous look
4. `mission/:id` route handler just have concrete logic without garbage

Check this solution:

```
const cors = require('cors'); // install: npm i --save cors
const _ = require('lodash'); // install:  npm i --save lodash

app.use(cors());

const isUserAuthorized = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
  next();
}

app.put(
  '/missions/:id', 
  isUserAuthorized, 
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const mission = await model.Mission.findById(req.params.id);
      if (!mission) return res.status(404).send();

      mission.set(_.pick(req.body, ['secret_mission', 'start', 'complete']);
      await mission.save();

      res.status(201).send();
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send();
    }
  });
```

or if You don't care if record in db exist or not, so You can just push update directly:

```
app.put(
  '/missions/:id', 
  isUserAuthorized, 
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const data = _.pick(req.body, ['secret_mission', 'start', 'complete']);

      await model.Mission.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: data});

      res.status(201).send();
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I wanted to stick with  .then response method because I want to keep it consistent with the rest of my app.

I will have to look into using the 'app.use(cors);' to avoid using so much repetition.

Thanks for posting such a detailed response between your response and reviewing the docs it really helped!